# Correct way to loop through std::array<char*, N>

Tags: c++, pointers, stdarray

Consider the following std::array of pointers to char:

```c
std::array<char*, 10> m_arr;
```

I know I can loop through the array using the following code

```c
for(size_t i {0}; i < m_arr.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << m_arr.at(i) << std::endl;
    }
```

But this approach throws "Access violation reading location" exception, when the i-th element is not assigned correctly. For example the following code assigns the first two elements but the third element, `m_arr.at(3)`, raises the aforementioned error:

```c
    // test variables
    int x {100};
    double y {3.14};
    int* x_ptr {&x};
    double* y_ptr {&y};

    // std::array of pointer to char
    std::array<char*, 10> m_arr;

    // set the first two elements of m_arr
    char buf1[16];
    sprintf_s(buf1, "%p", x_ptr);
    m_arr.at(0) = buf1;
    char buf2[16];
    sprintf_s(buf2, "%p", y_ptr);
    m_arr.at(1) = buf2;

    for(size_t i {0}; i < m_arr.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << m_arr.at(i) << std::endl;
    }
```

I found out a quick fix around this by checking the i-th element with the last element of the array to skip unassigned elements but obviously that's not a clean answer

```c
for(size_t i {0}; i < m_arr.size(); i++) {
        if(m_arr.at(i) != m_arr.back()) {
            std::cout << m_arr.at(i) << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I believe there is a better way to loop through this array and avoid the error. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't think your "fix" actually fixes anything. Anyway, the issue is not with looping over the element. It is about de-referencing uninitialized pointers.

Comment: When you know the index will be valid, there is nothing wrong with using `operator[]` instead of `at`. In principal `at` has the overhead of checking the index every time it's called.

Comment: The first question would be: Why are you using `char*` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @UnholySheep This is probably the case where an underlying API function or similar uses `char *`, and the OP assumes that they must also use `char *` in their program to communicate with the API.  I've seen this erroneous assumption too often not to notice it.

Comment: @UnholySheep It's a bit complicated but std::string is not an option

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your array:

```
std::array<char*, 10> m_arr{}; // nullptr initialized
```

then you might check safety for non-nullptr value:

```
for (auto ptr : m_arr) {
    if (ptr) std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @NathanOliver: Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't so much in the way that you iterate the array, but rather what the array contains, and what you do with those contents: The issue is that you only initialised two of the pointers in the array. Reading the value, and indirecting through the uninitialised pointers results in undefined behaviour.

Here is a correct way to loop through only the initialised elements, relying on the knowledge that you had initialised first two:

```
for(size_t i {0}; i < 2; i++) {
```

Another approach is to initialise the other pointers to null, and check for that in the loop condition:

```
std::array<char*, 10> m_arr{}; // value initialisation
...
for(size_t i {0}; i < m_arr.size() && m_arr[i]; i++) {

// or with range-for:
for (char* ptr : m_arr) {
    if (!ptr)
        break;
    std::cout << ptr << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a fan of this type of iteration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
// ...
for (auto&& object : m_arr)
{
    cout << (object != nullptr ? object : "Null pointer") << endl;
}
```

Don't forget to initialize your array too, it'll save you some segmentation faults:

```
std::array<char*, 10> m_arr {};
```

Comment: @Blastfurnance My mistake, you're correct. I'll append my answer